# Calculating the height of a UILabel?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I wanted to know is it possible to get the height of a multi line `UILabel`? I'm developing a messaging application and wanted to achieve something like the iPhone messaging application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the property with `label.frame.size.height`

Comment: @TusharChutani if this question is what you were looking for, please mark it as accepted (the little tag to the left)

Answer (score 2):

You probably want the `-[UILabel sizeThatFits:]` method.  Here's what you do.  Let's say your UILabel is in the variable `myLabel`, and you've already set its width to whatever you want.

```
myLabel.text = @"This is my very long message which will probably need multiple lines to be displayed because it is very long.";

CGRect bounds = myLabel.bounds;

// Create a size that is the label's current width, and very very tall.
CGSize prototypeSize = CGSizeMake(bounds.size.width, MAXFLOAT);

// Ask myLabel how big it would be if it had to fit in prototypeSize.
// It will figure out where it would put line breaks in the text to
// fit prototypeSize.width.
CGSize fittedSize = [myLabel sizeThatFits:prototypeSize];

// Now update myLabel.bounds using the fitted height and its existing width.
myLabel.bounds = (CGRect){ bounds.origin, CGSizeMake(bounds.size.width, fittedSize.height) };
```

Answer (score 0):

If you call

```
[label sizeToFit];
```

it will resize the UILabel to the minimum size needed to hold all the content.  Then you can just do label.frame.size.height to get the height of the label with that amount of text in it.

Comment: OP is looking to retrieve the height, not resize the contents

Comment: I disagree with your assumption.  This is a nice answer.

Comment: I assumed he wanted the height that the text in the label was taking up, not the height of the label (which he most likely specified when creating the label).